Decompose a function of multiple variables to product of functions of single variable
For simplicity, we consider a two variable function $f = f(x,y): \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$.
As stated in this post, in general, we can't write
$$f(x,y) = g(x) h(y)$$
as a product of single variable functions,
for some $g = g(x)$ and $h = h(y)$.
My question is following:
Can we decompose $f$ into an infinite sum of functions of separation variable, that is,
do there exist sequence $(g_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ and $(h_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ of functions of single variable such that
$$f(x,y) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} g_n(x) h_n(y)$$
for all $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$?
Any hint or example is welcome.

Sufficiently nice functions can be written in this form: just look at the Taylor series.

What sense of convergence are you looking for?

@strugglingmathematician For simplicity, we consider in the sense of pointwise convergence. But, my goal is convergence in $L^2$...

@nyan For the case of $L^2$ (or more generally $L^p$) see here.

$L^2$ is (sometimes) far more simple than pointwise convergence. Consider Carleson's theorem re convergence of Fourier series.
